# Question about analytic continuation of a function defined by an integral

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, analytic-continuation

Suppose I have a function  $f$ define
\begin{align}
f(x)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty   e^{-x^2t} g(t) dt.
\end{align}
where $g(t)$ is some positive, integrable fucntion

We also know that $f(x)$ has a power series representation 
\begin{align}
f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n x^n
\end{align}
which is valid for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

The existance of a power series also implies that there exists and entire function $h(z)$ such that
\begin{align}
h(z)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n z^n
\end{align}
for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $f(x)=h(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

My question now concerns the integral part of the defintion of $f(x)$.

Can I related $\int_{-\infty}^\infty   e^{-x^2t} g(t) dt$ to $h(z)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the analytic continuation is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-z^2 t}\ g(t)\ dt$ wherever the integral converges.

(Note that this is indeed an analytic function of $z$, since $e^{-z^2t}$ is analytic for each $t$, and if one makes suitable assumptions on $g(t)$ such that the integral converges then those same assumptions will allow us to interchange the derivative and integral to verify the Cauchy-Riemann equations for analyticity.)

Comment: Ok. Can you explain a little more? For example,  why is it not $\int e^{-|z|^2t}g(t) dt$?  Also, can you tell me more about this "whenever it converges" statement?

Comment: Well, from your assumptions all that can be  said is that $f(0)$ converges, it is not even necessarily true that $f(x)$ converges for real values of $x$ (for example, the integral for $f(1)$ diverges already when $g(t)=1/(t^2+1)$ since the integrand is unbounded as $t\to\infty$. You will need to make some stronger assumptions on $g(t)$ (for example, faster than exponential decay) if you want the function to converge everywhere. It seems that most reasonable conditions that guarantee convergence of $f(x)$ will also guarantee convergence for the analytic continuation.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use the same letter $g$ for two different functions in the statement of your question, it is confusing.

Comment: Thanks. Correct the confusion with $g$'s.